# Unicode Uppercase / Lowercase

Tags: windows, unicode

In the Win32-API there are two Functions called CharLowerBuff and CharUpperBuff. Fo both there are char- and Unicode-variants (the Unicode-APIs of Win32 were changed fom UCS-2 to UTF-16 some time ago, see article "Unicode in Microsoft Windows" in the Wikipedia). What I wondered was, that the length of the variable length UTF-16 character entities must remain the same if the characters were changed to uppercase or lowercase because the CharLower/UpperBuffW doesn't change the length of the buffer.

So does the Unicode-standard mandate that for languages with mixed case characters the two characters matching each other must be in a character-range that results in the same length character encoding with UTF-16?

Comment: Your actual question seems to be exclusively about Unicode and what the standard says, and not really about anything related to Windows.

Comment: I don't think the standard could mandate any such thing. I don't know about UTF-16, but for UTF-8, there are characters which have a legacy Latin-1 code point for lower case, but no such code point for upper case. Round-tripping those by necessity changes the length of the encoded character. Similarly I suppose there could be characters in the BMP which get an upper/lower pair outside the BMP in the future.

Comment: *Both* the functions you mention works with plain `char` characters as well ass wide-character `wchar_t` characters. It depends on the existence of the `UNICODE` macro if e.g. [the "ASCII" `CharLowerBuffA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-charlowerbuffa) or [the "Unicode" `CharLowerBuffW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-charlowerbuffw) function is used.

Comment: @triplee, maybe that's not true for UTF-8 but UTF-16. Windows must maintain the overall length for the above mentioned functions in their UTF-16-variant. So there must be such a guarantee.

Comment: So is your question then "does Windows make this guarantee for selfish reasons, or is there also a Unicode standard which requires this"?

Comment: @tripleee: I asked if there's such a guarantee of the Unicode-standard - at least for UTF-16.

Comment: `CharLowerBuffW` and `CharUpperBuffW` internally call `LCMapStringEx`, using the current user locale and file-system casing rules. In general it's better to call `LCMapStringEx` directly and include the flag `LCMAP_LINGUISTIC_CASING` to use locale casing rules.

Comment: That said, the NLS API up-cases all codes in the BMP to single-code values (e.g. "ß" up-cases as just "ß" instead of "SS"). In contrast, with the version of the Unicode database in Python 3.8, I find 102 codes in the BMP that up-case to a string of length 2 or 3. Of those, up-casing via Windows NLS returns the value unchanged for 75 codes and changed for 27. For example, for "ᾀ" ([U+1F80](https://codepoints.net/U+1F80)), Python up-cases it as "ἈΙ" (U+1F08, U+0399) and title-cases it as "ᾈ" (U+1F88), but the NLS API up-cases and title-cases it as the simple upper case value "ᾈ" (U+1F88).

Comment: CharUpperBuff is a legacy function for backward compatibility and does not work with strings whose uppercase version is a different length from lowercase. use LCMapStringEx instead.